# If-Modified-Since in Asp.Net Web Api 2

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In my current project I'm using Angularjs with Asp.net Web Api 2 and trying to use some headers to determine workflow.

In one situation I want to update an entity only if "If-Modified-Since"-header is set and the value is the same as the stored entity.

My angular code looks like following:

```
$http.patch(selfLink, {message: item.message},
    {
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "If-Modified-Since": item.LastModified
        }
    }
)
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if (successCallback) {
        successCallback();
    }
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if (errorCallback) {
        errorCallback(data, status);
    }
});
```

The Web Api code looks like following:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch(int id, JObject updateEntity)
{
    using(var session = this.store.OpenAsyncSession())
    {
        var entity = await session.LoadAsync<TEntity>(id);
        if(entity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if(Request.Headers.IfModifiedSince.HasValue == false)
        {
            return BadRequest("Missing If-Modified-Since header");
        }

        // More code
    }

}
```

Every request I make I will get `Request.Headers.IfModifiedSince.HasValue == false`, but then I'm trying `Request.Headers.GetValue("If-Modified-Since")` I will get the value I'm asking for.

Does anyone know why the `Request.Headers.IfModifiedSince` property is not set?

Answer (score 2):

Check the date format that you're sending as the header value. The date must be formatted according to the [RFC 1123](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#RFC1123) standard.  If

```
Request.Headers.GetValue("If-Modified-Since")
```

is not in this format, that would explain why

```
Request.Headers.IfModifiedSince
```

is null.